# Automate time and date through telnet

Tags: telnet

im not very clued up with telnet commands but i am looking to automate logins for a device we use in the field. we are having issues with Cmos batteries and every time the power goes out (6 times a day) we have to telnet into 2 devices then reset the dates on both of them.

im looking for a easy way to this like creating a .BAT file if possible.

usually like this

C:\Users\Administrator>Telnet 192.168.100.71

Debian GNU/Linux 3.0 quadras
quadras login: root
Password:desi

From here we type: date

then type: date -s "09 Jul 2022 10:55:00"

date gets changed and we type reboot.

Is there a way I can do this automatically. i appreciate any help given. TIA

Comment: You can pipe an input script into telnet. Where's your problem? You might also want to consider a UPS.

Comment: Ups is already being considered but client is currently out of money and we have to deal with it till December. This is the reason for asking here. Next. As I said I'm not to clued up with scripts. I don't know what you mean by "pipe an input script" consider me someone that has no knowledge of this stuff.

Comment: A small UPS is very rapidly less costly than paying people six times each day for a three-minute fix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to exec `date` command. The best is to install `ntp` software and sync time with time servers from internet.
[Here is one manual](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-debian-10) how to do this for Debian.

(something like)

1. Install `ntp`: `apt-get install ntpd`
2. start `ntpd`: `systemctl start ntpd`
3. check the status of `ntp` daemon: `systemctl status ntpd`
4. check peer servers: `ntpd -p`
5. In case of big time difference use `ntpd -gq` to force time set